# Developing Client/Server On A Non-Application Layer

Tags: networking, network-programming

How can I develop a network application (client/server) that will work in the transport or network layers of the ISO OSI model? For example: if I don't wan't the system to pack a data in a TCP or UDP packet, but instead I want to use my own protocol? How can I achieve that?

Help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Do a Google search for "raw sockets".

Comment: Thanks!!! But as far as i understand raw sockets allows me to work at transport layer level. What about the network layer? Is it possible to access it in user mode (Windows \ Linux)?

Comment: You want to be able to construct your own ethernet frames? Might be possible if you read/write directly from/to the network driver.

Comment: I want to avoid that. Some magic system service (or a magical library)..can help alot..

Comment: You can try using [PCAP](http://www.tcpdump.org/). See [this HOWTO](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/send_an_arbitrary_ethernet_frame_using_libpcap.html).

Comment: Great - Thanks alot! (I think your answer deserves to be an answer, not a comment...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the transport layer you should use [raw sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket).

For the network layer you could use e.g. [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/). See [here](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/send_an_arbitrary_ethernet_frame_using_libpcap.html) for a simple HOWTO.